# android java : persisitent login application

Tags: android, persistent

I am trying to make an persistent login application which then read sms from my phone and sends them to the an api with meaage body as well as the date and sender information. How can I proceed for the same. 
I have made the login app but persistent login like facebook and other applications is not working.

Here is my code for the login application:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class LoginActivity extends ActionBarActivity {


    private EditText un,pw;

    private Button sign;

    private TextView msg;
    private String resp, errorMsg;




    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        un = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Username);
        pw = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.et_Password);
        sign = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bt_SignIn);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);




        sign.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                /**
                 * According with the new StrictGuard policy, running long tasks
                 * on the Main UI thread is not possible So creating new thread
                 * to create and execute http operations
                 */
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                                un.getText().toString()));
                        postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                                pw.getText().toString()));

                        String response = null;
                        try {
                            response = SimpleHttpClient
                                    .executeHttpPost(
                                            url,
                                            postParameters);
                            String res = response.toString();
                            System.out.println(res);
                            resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                            errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                        }
                    }
                }).start();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);

                    /**
                     * Inside the new thread we cannot update the main thread So
                     * updating the main thread outside the new thread
                     */

                    msg.setText(resp);
                    if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
                        msg.setText(errorMsg);
                    }


                } catch (Exception e) {
                    msg.setText(e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

I tried this now,got the idea for shred prefernece but somewhow its not working for me
I tried this it doesn't show my main activity:
Can you find the problem:

```
MainActivity:

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    private String resp, errorMsg;
    private EditText username,password;
    /*public static final String MyPREFERENCES = "MyPrefs" ;
    public static final String name = "nameKey";
    public static final String pass = "passwordKey";
    SharedPreferences sharedpreferences;*/
    SessionManager session;

    private TextView msg;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        password = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        msg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_error);
        session = new SessionManager(this);
    }
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        //sharedpreferences=getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES,
               // Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (session.getuser()!=null)
        {
            if(session.getpassword()!=null){
                Intent i = new Intent(this,
                        Welcome.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }
        }

        super.onResume();
    }

    public void login(View view){

        String u = username.getText().toString();
        String p = password.getText().toString();

        {
            /**
             * According with the new StrictGuard policy, running long tasks
             * on the Main UI thread is not possible So creating new thread
             * to create and execute http operations
             */
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username",
                            username.getText().toString()));
                    postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password",
                            password.getText().toString()));

                    String response = null;
                    try {
                        response = SimpleHttpClient
                                .executeHttpPost(
                                        "<url>",
                                        postParameters);
                        String res = response.toString();
                        //System.out.println(res);
                        resp = res.replaceAll("\\s+", "");

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        errorMsg = e.getMessage();
                    }
                }
            }).start();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);

                /**
                 * Inside the new thread we cannot update the main thread So
                 * updating the main thread outside the new thread
                 */

                msg.setText(resp);
                if (null != errorMsg && !errorMsg.isEmpty()) {
                    msg.setText(errorMsg);
                }


            } catch (Exception e) {
                msg.setText(e.getMessage());
            }
        }




if (resp.contains("false")) {
    session.saveSession(u, p);

}
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }



}
```

Welcome:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Welcome extends Activity {

    SessionManager  session;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
        session = new SessionManager(this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
       //. getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    public void logout(View view){
        session.logoutUser();
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        Welcome.this.finish();
    }
    public void exit(View view){
        moveTaskToBack(true);
        Welcome.this.finish();
    }


    public List<Sms> getAllSms() {
        List<Sms> lstSms = new ArrayList<Sms>();
        Sms objSms = new Sms();
        Uri message = Uri.parse("content://sms/inbox");
        ContentResolver cr = this.getContentResolver();

        Cursor c = cr.query(message, null, null, null, null);
        this.startManagingCursor(c);
        int totalSMS = c.getCount();

        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < totalSMS; i++) {


                if(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("icicib")|| c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("hdfcbk") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("dbalrt")
                        ||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("citibk")||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("unionb")||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("atmsbi")
                        || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("sbiinb") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("indusb") ||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("fedbnk")
                        || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("kotakb")||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("axisbk")||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("pnbsms")
                        || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("hsbcin") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("canbnk") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("idbi")
                        ||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("iob") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("citibk") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("hdfcbk")
                        ||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("fromsc") ||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("myamex") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("26463872")
                        || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("sbicrd") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("icici?") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("syndbk")
                        || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("121") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("best deal(121)") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("airtel")
                        || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("vfcare") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("vodafone") || c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("mytsky")||c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")).contains("dishpy") ) {
                    objSms = new Sms();
                    objSms.setAddress(c.getString(c .getColumnIndexOrThrow("address")));
                    objSms.setMsg(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("body")));
                    objSms.setTime(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow("date")));


                    lstSms.add(objSms);
                }
                c.moveToNext();
            }
        }
        // else {
        // throw new RuntimeException("You have no SMS");
        // }
        c.close();

        return lstSms;
    }
}
```

SessionManager:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;


public class SessionManager {


    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;

    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

    private static final String PREFER_NAME = "AndroidExamplePref";

    public static final String KEY_USER = "username";

    public static final String KEY_PWD = "password";

    public SessionManager(Context context){
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREFER_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }


    public void saveSession(String user, String pwd){
        editor.putString(KEY_USER, user);
        editor.putString(KEY_PWD, pwd);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getuser()
    {
       String s =  pref.getString(KEY_USER,"");
        return s;
    }

    public String getpassword()
    {
        String p = pref.getString(KEY_PWD,"");
        return p;
    }

    public void logoutUser(){
        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();
        Intent i = new Intent(_context,.MainActivity.class);
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


}
```

AndroidManifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package=".sample" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.read_sms" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".Welcome"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_welcome" >
        </activity>
    </application>




</manifest>
```

UPDATED ANSWER:
IT works now
i made session as static and before logging I am checking the shared preference value and accordingly going ahead. Everything is working now.

Comment: save the userid after login and use the same userid in all url calls until the user logout from the app

Comment: @GeorgeThomas The user id would be easily modified (db or preferences) by anyone with a rooted device. A server-side generated token that would be in the login response is a more secure approach.

Comment: ya if security is concern @Gorcyn approach is best oauth token authentication will be good

Comment: @GeorgeThomas When is security not a concern? :D

Comment: That's up to the developer..:D

Comment: I can either save username password to login or access token for security, but how to use that access token to authorize again...do you have a sample code?

Comment: About "how to use that access token to authorize again", we can't tell that because that will depend on the server side to allow you this.

Comment: my server returns me {"data": "false"} if wrong password and {"data": "true"} if right one

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are meaning "persistent login application" -> User will log in once & for the next time they will not need to log in again with user name & password, right?

For this the naive approach would be storing the username & password in shared preference / db. But its not a good approach as it stores the password.

Instead of doing this, you can store, the userId/access token (obtained from the response). You should also have an expiration time so that you can prompt for log in validating the userId/access token after certain time. 
Facebook seems to do the same thing I guess. E.g. if you clear data from on facebook app, then you does need to log in again.

I hope this gives you a direction.

### Updated Answer

I guess you are not clear about pref.getString() method. The overloaded method (with 2 param) will return the 2nd param you sent, if any value with the query KEY (the 1st param)is not found.

In your case, in

```
public String getuser()
    {
       String s =  pref.getString(KEY_USER,""); // here is the error, "" is not null, its an empty String.
        return s;
    }
```

So you can change this trouble causing line into either of the following line-

```
String s =  pref.getString(KEY_USER,null);
```

or

```
String s =  pref.getString(KEY_USER);
```

Same problem in the `getuser()`. Hopefully this will solve your problem :)

Comment: I can save the response, but how to reuse it again..in code how to implement that approach

Comment: 1. We don't know what are you getting in the response.
About how to implement-
1. before launching login activity , you should check if you had already the userid/access token in your storage. If you have then you can move on to post authentication flow. And if you don't have that already, go on with the regular flow.

Comment: I tired he below code please tell me whats wrong in that... it showing welcome activity instead of main

Comment: @surbhi, your
 public String getpassword()
    {
        String p = pref.getString(KEY_PWD,"");
        return p;
    }
is not returning null in onResume() of MainActivity. As you are getting empty string if no value is obtained from pref with key "KEY_PWD". you should change into -
String p = pref.getString(KEY_PWD,null);

Comment: see my updated answer. Kindly accept the answer if this solves your problem

Comment: IT didnt help, I changed it but my screen is going to welcome instead of the main screen and if i remove onresume it shows main screen
I tried checking the the credentials before showing main activity it also showing error